# NodeJS res.json with wrong password

Tags: node.js

I have no idea, How to add res.json here if there is an invalid password? At this moment is if valid -> will change password, if not? nothing.. no console log.

```
router.put('/changePassword', function (req, res, next) {
  User.comparePassword(req.body.old, req.user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (err) {
      console.log('invalid password');
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.new, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          var newPassword = hash
          User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user._id },
            {
              $set: {
                password: newPassword,
              }
            },
            {
              upsert: true
            },
            ((newPassword) => {
              res.send(newPassword)
            }))
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't expect the console.log to happen because your first `if(err)` will throw before then.

Comment: Ok i removve first if(err) and still when I insert wrong password is nothing, no console, what now???

Comment: Secondly, it looks like you need to check your `isMatch` callback variable to determine if there was a password match or not. At least thats what I'm assuming from variable names.